# Accessing controls in loop when Option Strict is set to ON

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a loop which changes the color of all label on a winform under certain circumstances.  I am simply looping through all controls and then if its a label, change the forecolor.  However, as per business standards I must set Option Strict On, at which point I get errors about late binding the "container" variable.

I simply call setlabelColors(me) in my main thread when needed

Any thoughts??

```
Private Sub setlabelColors(ByVal container As Object)
        For Each control As Object In container.Controls
            If TypeOf control Is Label Then
                control.forecolor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(RGB(205, 207, 182))
            ElseIf TypeOf control Is Panel Or TypeOf control Is GroupBox Then
                setlabelColors(control)
            End If

        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object` can be any possible type with any combination of properties. To avoid late binding just change it to be a `Control`, which includes a control collection.

```
Private Sub setlabelColors(ByVal container As Control)
```

You'll also need to change your loop to:

```
For Each control As Control In container.Controls
```

There's no reason to get `control` as an `Object` since every element of `container.Controls` is a `Control`.

Comment: this now shows errors on control.forecolor and the recursive call to istelf

Comment: `code` Private Sub setlabelColors(ByVal container As ContainerControl)
        For Each control In container.Controls
            If TypeOf control Is Label Then
                control.forecolor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(RGB(205, 207, 182))
            ElseIf TypeOf control Is Panel Or TypeOf control Is GroupBox Then
                setlabelColors(control)
            End If

        Next
    End Sub `code`

Comment: You cannot post multiline code in the comments. Please tell me the errors though.

Comment: Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'ContainerControl'.

Comment: ok, now just the error on  setlabelColors(control).  again I get the error Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Control' to 'ContainerControl'

Comment: @LordNodralIII : Sorry for the inconvenience, I barely use `Option Strict` myself :). I have updated the answer again, though I was about to post that fix the first time but I thought it wasn't **that** strict.

Comment: @LordNodralIII : Actally I just noticed that the `GroupBox` doesn't inherit from `ContainerControl`, let me fix that as well.

Comment: @LordNodralIII : I hope that should do it. I changed everything to a `Control` instead. Very sorry for this, I thought it would be an easier fix and I'm writing this from my phone so I cannot test it myself.

Comment: @LordNodralIII : Glad I could finally help. Good luck with your project!